# Condition for finding rows with same value in one colum and null in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a table with columns student ID, subject, Enrolled. I have a row for each subject against a student. I am inserting this data to a temp table for reporting. I have another column named reporting in this temp table. I need to update reporting false when enrolled is null for all the rows imported for a student.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach:

- Select from all students
- Left outer join to student-course (outer join is important here)
- Group by student ID, and get min course ID
- Use rows with null course ID to decide what temp rows to update

In SQL this query would look like this:

```
SELECT StudentId, MIN(CourseId)
FROM Student s
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentCourse sc
    ON s.StudentId=sc.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId
HAVING MIN(CourseId) IS NULL
```